# Viewing files shared with second account on Google drive

Tags: gmail, google-drive, google-account

I have a second Google account/email address. When someone emails a shared document to that email address, I have to sign out of my primary Google account and sign in with the other to view it.

In the case of emails, I forward everything on to my primary account so I don't need to sign out/in to check them.

Is there a way I can similarly have my second account give access to my primary account to view all its shared documents automatically? I.e. I want to be able to just click on the document in the email I get via the second account and view it without any mucking around.

Comment: You shouldn't need to log out. Google multiple login should allow you to quickly switch between accounts in Gmail and Google Drive.